# Changing collation on indexed columns without changing data

Tags: mysql, indexing, blob, collation

I am trying to change the collation on a bunch of columns. I don't want to mess up my current data, so I've been looking at doing something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29068055/771665):

> `ALTER TABLE something MODIFY name BLOB;`
>
> The next step is to convert the column to a nonbinary data type with the proper character set:
>
> `ALTER TABLE something MODIFY name VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET hebrew COLLATE hebrew_bin;`
>
> Or Try with this:
>
> `ALTER TABLE something MODIFY name VARCHAR(12) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`

Unfortunately, mysql won't let me convert an indexed column to a blob.

> SQL error: [1170] - BLOB/TEXT column 'baz' used in key specification without a key length
>
> Query: `ALTER TABLE foo.bar MODIFY baz blob;`

Is there a way around this? Or do I need to somehow remove my indexes and rebuild them after the conversion?

Comment: Collation orders chars in a character set and indexes are sorted so you will have to drop them anyway and rebuild on a new collation. Changing collation on the same character set won't mess up data.

Comment: @piotrm Do you want to make this the answer? I think it pretty much answers my question. It would be nice if you added **how** to drop the indexes and then re-add them pseudo-programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do the "2-step ALTER" unless the `CHARACTER SET` was wrong but the data was 'right'.  If you want to convert *both* the `CHARACTER SET` and the data, use
    ALTER TABLE something CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET ...;

See Case 5 in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#conversions_and_common_errors), which, as you might guess, has other cases.

As for the error 1170 -- that had to do with some `INDEX`.  Before I help you with that, decide whether it is relevant.